# ffplay udp streaming error and quality issue

Tags: streaming-video, streaming, ffmpeg

I am receiving UDP streaming through ffmpeg ffplay, but there is a problem that the video is broken.
I'm using a GoPro Hero 10 camera, but I can't receive more than three camera streams because the streaming is fixed with the UDP 8554 port.

So using Raspberry Pi 4 and nginx reverse proxy for each camera, multi camera streaming successfully received on another Raspberry Pi.

In conclusion, GoPro camera UDP streaming -> Raspberry Pi received. use nginx reverse proxy -> another Raspberry Pi received.

However, there is an issue that streaming video quality is broken.
I used ffplay:
`ffplay udp://@:23002`

and the following error also appears:

```
[h264 @ 0x91cb4ed0] reference picture missing during reorderf=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x91cb4ed0] Missing reference picture, default is 65559
[h264 @ 0x91d234d0] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0x91d234d0] Missing reference picture, default is 65559
[h264 @ 0x93028ba0] reference picture missing during reorderf=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x93028ba0] Missing reference picture, default is 65560
[h264 @ 0x9302d6d0] mmco: unref short failure 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x9302d6d0] number of reference frames (0+3) exceeds max (2; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[mpegts @ 0x93000630] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 73156083)
[mpegts @ 0x93000630] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 73159086)
[mpegts @ 0x93000630] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 73165092)
[h264 @ 0x9302d6d0] reference picture missing during reorderf=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x9302d6d0] Missing reference picture, default is 65540
[h264 @ 0x930e08e0] reference picture missing during reorderf=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x930e08e0] Missing reference picture, default is 65541
```

so I use the ffplay option `-fflag +discardcorrupt` and
use `-vf "setpts=N/60/TB"`.

Conclusion: `ffplay udp://@:23002 -fflag +discardcorrupt -vf "setpts=N/60/TB"`

[image: streaming_img]

It's better than before, but still breaks when the change in streaming video is large.

And the packet corrupt still remains, I don't know how to set the pts value that fits the streaming video.

Or is there an issue that I didn't find?

I'm looking for a way to match the pts.

But I wonder if this is the right way.

I'd appreciate your help to the lost.

Comment: Not Pi relevant.  Perhaps ask on a general forum or target the question to gopro/ffmpeg specifically.